# Connecting a Unity3D program and Python script remotely?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, server

First, I will admit I'm a bit out of my depth with this issue.

I have a Unity program that gathers and can output numerical data in the form of a vector of values. I also have separate Python code that runs a reinforcement learning agent based on the numerical data. The code can already output a decision based on an inputted vector. Ideally, several instances of the Unity program will be running at the same time all sending data to one main instance of the Python scripts. However, the Python code needs to be able to respond to the Unity programs whenever they send data.

In the past for data collection, I've made use of a web server that the Unity program can call to upload data to a central place. However, the Python code needs to receive a data vector and then send the Unity program a response based on the data, so the one-way uploading method does not work here.

Comment: "so the one-way uploading method does not work here." - webserver isnt "one way", it can return data in its response. Or is it not suitable for some reason?

Comment: what about a simple TCP connection? As the [c# Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) Connect -> send data -> wait for response, and on the [python server](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication#Server) Listen for connection -> accept connection -> receive data -> calculations? -> send response